# class="parent" for wp_list_pages?

Tags: php, functions, pages

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_pages('exclude=&title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

creates the following output...

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page with Subpages</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="#">Page with another subpage</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="#">subsubpage</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

All pages with children have a `ul class="children"` applied. Is it possible to create any function (or any other way) to append a classname to all pages THAT HAVE CHILDREN? In my example above only the "Page with Subpages" and it's first child-page "Page with another subpage" should have a `li.parent` applied.

Is that possible on the serverside? I'm able to do it with javascript, however I wonder if there is a better and cleaner way to do it serverside?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Phew! Bit more complex than I would've liked - if only the filter `page_css_class` passed back `$args` it would save a lot of effort (may submit this to trac).</strike>

**Since 3.3** it's as easy as this!

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class, $page, $depth, $args )
{
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'parent';
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

For those on pre WordPress 3.3, here's the workhorse:

```
/**
 * Extend the default page walker class to append class names for pages that
 * are parents.
 * @uses Walker_Page
 */ 
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page
{
    /**
     * Filter in the classes for parents.
     */
    function _filterClass( $class )
    {
        $class[] = 'parent'; // change this to whatever classe(s) you require
        return $class;
    }

    /**
     * This is effectively a wrapper for the default method, dynamically adding
     * and removing the class filter when the current item has children.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page )
    {
        if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
            add_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );

        parent::start_el( $output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page );

        if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
            remove_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );
    }
}
```

I'd advise placing the class in your `functions.php`, then it's available wherever you'd like to use it.

To use it, call `wp_list_pages()` like so;

```
// You need to pass the walker argument to wp_list_pages(). You must use an
// array to do this.
wp_list_pages(array(
    'walker'   => new My_Page_Walker,
    'title_li' => ''
));
```

Comment: you are amazing! thank you very much. didn't mean to ask a question that ends in a mega answer. I hope this will help others as well. thank you again!

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17727 - would be a nice improvement I think :)

Comment: Patch made it to core! Answer updated.

Comment: I'm running WordPress v3.4.1. I had to use `$args['has_children']` instead of `$args['children']`.

Answer (score -1):

I guess there is a more simple solution for that, you could add the following filter in the functions.php file in the theme folder. You don't have to change anything else.

```
add_filter('page_css_class', 'check_parent', 10, 2 );

function check_parent($css_class, $page) {
    if (wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$page->ID."&echo=0"))
        array_push($css_class, "parent");
    return $css_class;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ewww, look at all those db queries! I've updated my answer for >=3.3