# How to use custom fields to replace top-level parent title with an image using wp_list_pages?

Tags: php, custom-field, images, wp-list-pages

I'd like to integrate `get_post_meta` into the `wp_list_pages` mix so that any top-level parent list items get replaced with images ONLY when a key exists in the post's custom fields section. I can't do it with the Featured Image b/c that's already being used for another purpose inside the post itself.

Here's my Walker_Page class in functions.php:

```
/**
 * Extend the default page walker class to append class names for pages that
 * are parents.
 * @uses Walker_Page
 *
 * http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/class-parent-for-wp-list-pages
 *
 */ 
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page
{
    /**
     * Filter in the classes for parents.
     */
     function _filterClass( $class )
     {
         $class[] = 'parent'; // change this to whatever classe(s) you require
         return $class;
     }

     /**
      * This is effectively a wrapper for the default method, dynamically adding
      * and removing the class filter when the current item has children.
      */
     function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page )
     {
         if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
             add_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );

         parent::start_el( $output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page );

         if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
             remove_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );
     }
 }
```

So, I'm currently using `wp_list_pages` to show Custom Post Type posts like this:

```
<ul class="items"><?php
$args = array(
    'walker'=>new My_Page_Walker,
    'post_type' => 'region',
    'menu_class' => 'nav-menus',
    'title_li' => ''
);
wp_list_pages($args);
?>
</ul>
```

It spits out the following code:

```
<ul class="items">
     <li class="page_item page-item-123 parent"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/" title="city">City</a>
        <ul class='children'>
           <li class="page_item page-item-124 parent"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/suburb/" title="Suburb">Suburb</a>
              <ul class='children'>
                 <li class="page_item page-item-125"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/suburb/complex/" title="Complex">Complex</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

and I'd like the following:

```
<ul class="items">
     <li class="page_item page-item-123 parent"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/" title="city"><img src="city-name.jpg" alt="City" /></a>
        <ul class='children'>
           <li class="page_item page-item-124 parent"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/suburb/" title="Suburb">Suburb</a>
              <ul class='children'>
                 <li class="page_item page-item-125"><a href="/wordpress/region/city/suburb/complex/" title="Complex">Complex</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

where `city-name.jpg` is defined in the custom fields section. It should only show up for the post title that has a custom field.

Is this a really complex amount of code where I can't use `wp_list_pages`? I honestly can't find an answer online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the #wordpress irc channel and was given the answer by [Marko Heijnen](https://twitter.com/#!/markoheijnen). He grabbed the Walker Code from /wp-includes/post-template.php and added a few lines to it.

```
/**
 * Extend the default page walker class to append class names for pages that
 * are parents.
 * @uses Walker_Page
 *
 * http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/class-parent-for-wp-list-pages
 *
 */ 
class My_Page_Walker extends Walker_Page
{
/**
 * Filter in the classes for parents.
 */
 function _filterClass( $class )
 {
     $class[] = 'parent'; // change this to whatever classe(s) you require
     return $class;
 }

 /**
  * This is effectively a wrapper for the default method, dynamically adding
  * and removing the class filter when the current item has children.
  */
 function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page )
 {
     if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
         add_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );

    if ( $depth )
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    else
        $indent = '';

    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);
    if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
        $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
        _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);
        if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
        elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }

    $css_class = implode(' ', apply_filters('page_css_class', $css_class, $page));

    $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before;
    $image = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'title_image', true);
    if ( isset($image) && !empty($image) ) {
        $output .= '<img src="'. $image .'" alt="'. apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) .'" />';
    }
    else {
        $output .= apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID );
    }
    $output .=  $link_after . '</a>';

    if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
        if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
            $time = $page->post_modified;
        else
            $time = $page->post_date;

        $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
    }


     if ( !empty($args['has_children']) )
         remove_filter( 'page_css_class', array( &$this, '_filterClass') );
 }
}
```