# Change ul class="children" for wp_list_pages?

Tags: functions, wp-list-pages

Hello I'm using this code to print a list of Pages and Subpages:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=2&child_of='); ?>
</ul>
```

It outputs:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Subpage 2a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subpage 2b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Subpage 3a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subpage 3b</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to override the `<ul class="children">` for something else in the **functions.php**? like `<div class="container"><div class="container2"><ul>` and the closing to `</ul></div></div>`

I was checking [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/class-parent-for-wp-list-pages#_=_) but I don't know how to apply it to my case... Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can override this by supplying your on `Walker` Object when calling `wp_list_pages`, like this:

**<your-template>.php**

```
wp_list_pages(array(
    'title_li' => null,
    'depth' => 2,
    'child_of' => 0,
    'walker' => new My_Walker(),
));
```

Instead of the default `Walker_Page` this will make `wp_list_pages` use your custom walker, `My_Walker`. The only difference we need here is to make your entire list wrapped in the two divs you described in your question. To do this we need to override the methods `start_lvl` and `end_lvl` of `Walker_Page`. As defined below, the list will be wrapped in two divs when it's on level 0 (the top most level), while subsequent lists will be plain `ul` elements.

**functions.php**

```
class My_Walker extends Walker_Page {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='container'><div class='container2'><ul>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
        }
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "$indent</ul></div></div>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as described in the link you supplied, just override the page_css_class and wrap each function call with your divs manually:

**functions.php**

```
function add_parent_class( $css_class = array(), $page = null, $depth = null, $args = array() )
{
    if ( ! empty( $args['has_children'] ) )
        $css_class = array();
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'add_parent_class', 10, 4 );
```

**<your-template>.php**

```
<div class="container"><div class="container2"><ul>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=2&child_of='); ?>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! Thanks a lot :D I was going crazy with it!

Comment: There are lot of warning messages... 
Warning: Missing argument 2 for add_parent_class()

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman: Perhaps WordPress (or another filter) is not supplying all of the function parameters for the `page_css_class` filter (anymore). Just add some default values for your callback function and you should be fine. See updated answer for details.

Comment: Can I do same thing for `li` of children `ul` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The `add_parent_class` callback function will remove any css classes for pages having child pages, but I'm not sure how that would apply to `li`s in this case. If you want to add other classes or remove them in other cases, just modify the code to suit your needs.