# wp_list_pages change <ul> of children and anchor of parent

Tags: functions, wp-list-pages

I am getting the list of Pages and Subpages by `wp_list_pages()`.

I want to change the parent `<a>` and `<ul>` child. I found a solution [here in this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83565/change-ul-class-children-for-wp-list-pages/83593?noredirect=1#comment172710_83593).

But It only changes the `<ul>`.

How can I add classes/attributes to the both (`<a>` and `<ul>`) at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Walker: extend the Walker_Nav_Menu class in your functions.php

```
class custom_nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el (&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $item_output = '<a href="' . $item->url. '" someattr="somevalue">' . $item->title . '</a>';
    $output .= '<li>' . apply_filters ('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item,  $depth, $args);
  }
}
```

and call it in `wp_list_pages`

```
<?php wp_list_pages(array( 'walker' => new custom_nav ())); ?>
```